# Java algorithm problem: output one of the two connected paths

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm, union-find

```
/**
* The Problem:
*
* We have a list of tasks. Each task can depend on other tasks. 
* For example if task A depends on task B then B should run before A.
* 
* Implement the "getTaskWithDependencies" method such that it returns a list of task names in the correct order.
* 
* For example if I want to execute task "application A", the method should return a list with "storage,mongo,application A".
*
* List of Tasks:
*
*   - name: application A
*     dependsOn:
*       - mongo
*
*   - name: storage
*
*   - name: mongo
*     dependsOn:
*       - storage
*
*   - name: memcache
*
*   - name: application B
*     dependsOn:
*       - memcache
*
* The Java program is expected to be executed succesfully.
*/
public class Solution { 
 private static List<String> getTaskWithDependencies(List<Task> tasks, String dependsOn) {
   // TODO: please implement logic here
   
 }
  
  

 @Test
 public void testGetTaskDependenciesForApplicationA() {
   Assert.assertEquals(
     Arrays.asList(
       "storage",
       "mongo",
       "application A"
     ),
     getTaskWithDependencies(TaskList.getTasks(), "application A")
   );
 }
}

/**
* Definition of a Task
*/
class Task {
 private final String name;
 private final List<String> dependsOn;

 Task(String name) {
   this(name, new ArrayList<>());
 }

 Task(String name, List<String> dependsOn) {
   this.name = name;
   this.dependsOn = dependsOn;
 }

 public String getName() { return this.name; }
 public List<String> getDependsOn() { return this.dependsOn; }
}

class TaskList {
 public static List<Task> getTasks() {
   List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

   tasks.add(new Task("application A", Arrays.asList("mongo")));
   tasks.add(new Task("storage"));
   tasks.add(new Task("mongo", Arrays.asList("storage")));
   tasks.add(new Task("memcache"));
   tasks.add(new Task("application B", Arrays.asList("memcache")));

   return tasks;
 }
}
```

The general idea is to give some directional relationships, including:
application a -> mongodb -> storage This is a connecting path
application b -> memcache This is a connecting path,
Now that application A is specified, it is required to output the connected path where it is.
My approach is to sort these 5 points together using topological sorting. The result will be b->memcache->a->mongo->storage.
My question is: how to output only one connected path and ignore the other? I read there is no similar question in Leetcode, so there is no idea.
I can write the code by myself, and it’s good to be able to tell me the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *recursion* to solve your problem.

From the `list of tasks` passed in the method, fetch the one with `dependsOn` through filtering by `name` of the `task`. If the `task` has it's  own `dependsOn` list, iterate through the list and call the recursive function passing the same `list of tasks` and the iterated string as newDependsOn to it. Append all the results you get from the recursive function in a comma separated StringBuilder with a `","` which will be used as delimiter for producing final list.

After all these completion of iteration, append the initial `dependsOn` to the StringBuilder. Finally, return the `StrinBuilder.toStirng().split(",")` as list to get the final result.

**NOTE:** I've written the code but as per as your request I haven't added it to this answer. If you need further help, ask me in the comment, I'll provide the code if needed.

**Update**

As per your request I'm adding the code below:

```
private static List<String> getTaskWithDependencies(List<Task> tasks, String dependsOn) {
    StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder();
    Task task = tasks.stream().filter(x -> dependsOn.equalsIgnoreCase(x.getName())).findAny().get();
    if (task.getDependsOn() != null && !task.getDependsOn().isEmpty()) {
        for (String newDependsOn : task.getDependsOn()) {
            List<String> res = getTaskWithDependencies(tasks, newDependsOn);
            for (String ele : res) {
                resultString.append(ele).append(",");
            }
        }
    }
    resultString.append(dependsOn);
    return Arrays.asList(resultString.toString().split(","));
}
```

Now if you run the code with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getTaskWithDependencies(TaskList.getTasks(), "application A"));
}
```

You'll get the following output:

```
[storage, mongo, application A]
```

Comment: I feel a little abstraction. It would be great if you could provide the code. Thank you!

Comment: @JoyCheng I've updated the answer, please check now

Comment: May I ask if this line means: filter out tasks whose ‘name’ is equal to ‘dependsOn’ (that is, filter out each task itself)?
Task task = tasks.stream().filter(x -> dependsOn.equalsIgnoreCase(x.getName())).findAny().get();

Comment: the `dependsOn` refers to the name of any task. So, we're passing the name of the task in the `dependsOn` variable as per question's specification, and taking the task that matches the name with the `dependsOn` that we've passed to the method

Comment: Your code is very concise, and the use of Java 8 is also very smooth. It helped me a lot, thank you!